# how I can take a different value of r for each while loop in the following code?python

Tags: python, loops, class, while-loop

```
import random
class check_error:
def __init__(self,firstbyte=bytearray(b'\x15\x04\xA5')) :
    r=random.choice (firstbyte)
    self.r=r

def pocket_data(self):


    print("I am sending request for NBP/SpO2 datas")
    r=self.r

    while True:    
        print("blala")
        r=self.r
        print(r)

        try: 
            if int("{:02x}".format(r))==15:
                print("Negative Acknowledgment.Error occured during data transmission to device.I am sending the datas again... ")
                continue

            elif r==4:
                print("Host does not have the capability to respond to the request,it only supports a subset of the protocol")
                continue

        except:
            print("done")
            break   

s=check_error()
print(s.pocket_data())
```

the loop becomes endless if choosen element is x15 or x04 but what I am trying to do is choose a different element of bytearray until choosen element is xA5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize the class, `r` is set to `random.choice (firstbyte)`. Note that this is never changed; you set the value of `r`, then you assign `self.r = r`, and then you never change `self.r` again.

What you need to do, if you want `r` to continue rolling random numbers, is save `firstbyte` to a variable in the class - for example:

```
def __init__(self,firstbyte=bytearray(b'\x15\x04\xA5')) :
    self.firstbyte = firstbyte
    r=random.choice (firstbyte)
    self.r=r
```

Then, inside the loop, continue to generate random numbers the same way you did in the constructor:

```
while True:    
    self.r = random.choice(self.firstbyte)
    ...
```